# Attempt to update profile picture triggers "email address already registered error"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-page, profile-picture, askubuntu

When I try to update my StackExchange profile image I get the following error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: This email address is
>   already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our
>   account recovery page to get access to this account.

Tried in: askubuntu and stackoverflow.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open "My Profile"
2. Go to "Edit Profle and Settings"
3. "Change Picture"
4. Update picture (tried with URL and also with direct upload)
5. Click "Save and copy changes to all public communities"
6. Then I get the error. Changes are **not** saved.

Comment: There is a [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/354240/jesus-iniesta) with a simliar name to yours, perhaps you had another account in the past